# Does anyone know this Manhwa about a video game?

Tags: story-identification, manga

does anyone know this description of the Manhwa?

> It doesn't seem like it in the beginning, but it students that play in a game. The Manhwa start with the villain, poisonous snake that poison a girl and therefore her touch poison whatever she touches. There another player, a doctor, he does his best to cure her but ends up dying while protecting her. Having falling in love with her, he ask he friend to hack the system so that he can meet the girl again.

It was full color manga, the game was Chinese dynasty.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  Do you recall any of the character or place names?

Comment: Is what you've written a quote from somewhere or just your own description that you've decided to put into quote marks?